# Unloading Application Domain does not return?

Tags: appdomain

My question is about application domain created for loading/unloading dlls.
All started with the need of

```
Step-1 : load the dll
Step-2 : process that dll
Step-3 : Unload the dll
```

As we can not unload a dll, creating an Application Domain is inevitable, which is fine. So new steps are;

```
Step-1 : Create a new app domain
Step-2 : load the dll
Step-3 : process that dll
Step-4 : Unload the Application domain
```

My problem is about unloading part. Sometimes `AppDomain.Unload("newDomain");` does not return although i wait quite long. What may be the reason for the unload method not to return?
I have read MSDN for the following explanation.

> When a thread calls Unload, the target domain is marked for unloading.
>   The dedicated thread attempts to unload the domain, and all threads in
>   the domain are aborted. If a thread does not abort, for example
>   because it is executing unmanaged code, or because it is executing a
>   finally block, then after a period of time a
>   CannotUnloadAppDomainException is thrown in the thread that originally
>   called Unload. If the thread that could not be aborted eventually
>   ends, the target domain is not unloaded. Thus, in the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0 domain is not guaranteed to unload, because it might not
>   be possible to terminate executing threads.

But i have some questions.
1) What is the "Period of time" explained here? Can i set it?
2) MSDN says .NET 2.0 framework does not quarante to unload. How about .NET 4.0?
3) I am sure there is no thread running in the loaded dll. What may be the other reason?

i am badly stuck, any help is appreciated :(

Comment: Did you capture it in Visual Studio yet? I bet there is a thread, most likely the finalizer thread.

Comment: Yes definitely. I have debugged my code and after hitting `AppDomain.Unload()` line it never returns. Actually the dll contains communication with a serial port. And that serial port is added after installing the drivers for Arduino board. In the dll there is no thread, no loops etc. Just methods including open, write, close...

Comment: And do you create any objects which have a finalizer? There is always a finalizer thread. I expect the serial port object has one that closes the port.

Comment: i had a destructor which was like; `if (Port.isopen) Port.Close();` nothing more... After not being able to unload the appdomain, i deleted the destructor however nothing changes. Still can not return from unload.

Comment: Set up a new class in that domain with a single function which does `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`. Call that function in the domain on an new object. See if it ever returns.

Comment: @zsavas do you managed to solve your problem? I'm facing something like it, but in my case, unload method just hangs in a Azure virtual machine. Locally it unloads with no stuck or hangs. One more thing is that it never returns the exception that MSDN says. Thanks.