# AppDomain Unload hangs in .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have a problem with unloading an AppDomain in my .NET application.

I have the following code which simply loads dlls in a directory and checks if they have a certain attribute:

```
AppDomainSetup info = new AppDomainSetup();
Assembly arAssembly = typeof(AssemblyResolver).Assembly;
info.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(arAssembly.Location);

AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AssemblyResolver", null, info);

//Find all the assemblies with the attribute defined
AssemblyName[] assemblyNames = null;
AssemblyResolver ar = (AssemblyResolver)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(arAssembly.FullName, typeof(AssemblyResolver).FullName) as AssemblyResolver;
assemblyNames  = ar.PrivateFindAssembliesWithAttribute(attributeType, path, includeSubdirs);

//Finally unload the AppDomain
AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);       <-- HANGS HERE
appDomain = null;
```

This works fine for all my dlls that have the attribute in question.  BUT I have one dll that includes a reference to a 3rd party dll (PelcoSDK.dll, see: http://pdn.pelco.com/sdk#sthash.ERuOPMO6.dpbs )

Whenever this dll is included the following line just freezes:

```
AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
```

From this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f0f10ae-7fcb-459d-9112-6556a9b5b456/appdomainunload-deadlock?forum=csharplanguage I see that there are exceptions that can be thrown so I added the following:

```
try
{
    AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
    appDomain = null;
}
catch (CannotUnloadAppDomainException ex)
{
    string message = ex.Message;
}
catch (AppDomainUnloadedException ex)
{
    string message = ex.Message;
}
```

**BUT** the exceptions are never thrown.

**ALSO** I added in the following event handlers to see if there were any debug messages indicating why the Unload was not successful **but** there was nothing reported (**EventArgs were null**):

```
AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AssemblyResolver", null, info);
appDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler(defaultAD_DomainUnload);
appDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(defaultAD_ProcessExit);

public static void defaultAD_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unloaded defaultAD!");
}

private static void defaultAD_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unloaded defaultAD!");
}
```

Can anyone point to why the Unload would hang like this? Or any suggestions as to how to debug it?

Comment: are you sure exceptions are not thrown since the statements in the catch blocks seem to do nothing?

Comment: Unload cannot complete until all threads that execute code in the appdomain are aborted.  A thread won't abort when it is not in an alertable wait state or when it executes unmanaged code.  The latter clause ought to ring a bell :)  If you can't force that code to finish its job then the only other option you have is running it in another process that you can Kill().

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651497/unloading-application-domain-does-not-return suggests that it would eventually throw a CannotUnloadAppDomainException

Comment: I waited for a long time (30 mins) and it never threw an CannotUnloadAppDomainException

Comment: I put breakpoints in the exceptions and they were never hit.

Comment: you could also wrap the misbehaving 3rd-party dll in its own exe, launch it as a separate process and kill it when you are done. of course then you would need to find a way to communicate with it but that's another story.

Comment: We have a similar issue. Unfortunately as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 an attempt is made to abort threads executing within that AppDomain. 

Also unfortunately, .NET has no good way of forcing threads to die (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=vs.110).aspx). Just having an infinite loop in a finally block will prevent .NET from being able to terminate it. Also, unmanaged code that's waiting on an IO operation can block indefinitely.

Comment: Apparently this is also OS specific. Having this issue on Windows 10, but not on Server 2016 or Windows 7

Comment: I'm expiriencing the same problem. It seems that this is even installaion specific. I have a windows 10 installation where the unloading of the AppDomain works and one where it doesnt. In cases where AppDomain.Unload doesnt return I see several thrads "hanigng" at "WaitForSingleObject" in ProcessExplorer. Seems like a lock is never released...